# How can I download a file from its download link provided on a webpage using Delphi?

Tags: file, delphi, web

How can I download a file from its download link provided on a webpage using Delphi?
Please note that I am not using visual components. I am using IHTMLDocument2 to access the web.

Comment: [WinInet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586288/can-i-load-a-memo-or-rich-edit-from-a-text-file-on-server/4586333#4586333), [Indy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185308/282848), [UrlMon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506314/282848)... Really, there are many SO questions about this.

Answer (score 3):

For all modern Delphi version since Delphi XE8 you can use `THTTPClient` from unit  `System.Net.HttpClient`:

```
Procedure SimpleDownload(const DownloadUrl: string; Stream: TStream);
var
  Client: THTTPClient;
  Response: IHTTPResponse;
begin
  Client := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    Response := Client.Get(DownloadUrl, Stream);
    if Response.StatusCode = 200 then
      // Success case
    else 
      // Error case: Check Response.StatusText or StatusCode
  finally
    Client.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For download to a file call `SimpleDownload` with an instance of `TFileStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `IHTMLDocument2` is the API from the [MSHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801968(v=vs.85)) library, because AFAIK neither VCL nor CLX offers an API named as such.

As far as I know, MSHTML does not implement a generic download API - sometimes called a "HTTP client". You might be interested in using fcl-web from the Lazarus project - its a library meant for developing server applications but it also includes an HTTP client API named [`fphttpclient`](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fphttpclient).

Comment: Thank you. This is the working code I am using in my app now:
 
errcode := URLMon.URLDownloadToFile(nil,                    PChar('https://fonts.ge/ka/download/font/704/ALK-Sanet/alk-sanet_[FONTS.GE].zip'),PChar( 'D:\test.zip'),0,nil);

Comment: That looks like it could work, but @schneider-infosystems-ltd's solution seems like a much better idea.